# Can I have a C# solution with GTK that can be used in both Visual Studio and MonoDevelop/Xamarin Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, mono, monodevelop, gtk#, xamarin-studio

I created a C# solution with Xamarin Studio (on Mac) that uses GTK.  When I clone that to Windows and open it in Visual Studio, I'm disappointed to see that all the GTK references are broken.

In Xamarin, I see that the GTK libraries are in the Mono Framework, and not just simple dlls.  The references point to paths in `/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/' according to the UI, but in the underlying`.csproj` file, there is no path at all.

In Visual Studio, those references are broken, and the paths are empty.  The Mono for Windows installer (mono-3.2.3-gtksharp-2.12.11-win32-0.exe, in my case) does not add the GTK libs to the GAC (which seems like a dumb thing to not do).

Is there a way to get GTK# recognized by Visual Studio in a way that doesn't break the project for Xamarin Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Either install Xamarin Studio on the Windows machine or install GTK# by itself. You will not be able to design UI from Visual Studio but you will be able to build it and debug/run it.

http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html

Comment: Actually, I did install GTK# by itself, but I can't seem to find the libraries via the VS reference-browser dialog, except if I browse directly to them in their `C:\Program Files` location, which sounds like an awful thing to do.  What is the standard practice?

Comment: Maybe they did not get installed into GAC. You could try installing with 'gacutil -i <dllname.dll>'

Comment: Ooh, I didn't know about that one.  Will give it a shot.

Comment: I can install them into the GAC, but they rely on other dlls, like glibsharpglue-2.dll.  I *can't* install this one into the GAC (VS says it doesn't have an assembly manifest).

Comment: Maybe installing Xamarin on the machine will help? It's been a while since I installed GTK# by itself on Win-machine but the Xamarin installation works (Parallels, Mac & Win8.1).

Comment: Do you think installing Xamarin will get those GTK libraries into the GAC so that VS can use them?  I know that VS can't use the GTK designer, but I at least want VS to be able to build and run it.  I don't want to use Xamarin on Windows.

Comment: It worked for me so it's worth a shot. I would uninstall the standalone GTK# first.